# How to connect an algorithm to the input in QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I may well be missing something very easy, but how do you connect an algorithm in the QGIS graphical modeler to the Input?

I'm following an online tutorial and have added the Inputs into the Model; when i select the first Algorithm, complete the details for it (including the Input it needs to be connected to) and click OK, the algorithm appears but no connecting line.

Am i doing this correct, or is there something else i need to do to make the connection?

I'm using QGIS 3.16.8.

Screenshot[image: Screenshot of modeller window should be below]

The tutorial i'm following is:
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_graphical_modeler.html

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

For input layer, set `Use model input`, not the default `value` option.

> Model Input: choose this option if the parameter comes from an input
> of the model you have defined. Once clicked, this option will list all
> the suitable inputs for the parameter

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html?#definition-of-the-workflow

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Has anyone had the model input drop down empty? This is happening to me.